# how do I remove an item that is set to upload?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have created an uploader using javascript and php. The problem is that I only want to allow specific file types. I have it letting the user know the file is not valid but I am not sure how to remove the file from being uploaded. Can anyone tell me how to remove the upload?

```
multiUploader.prototype._preview = function(data) {
    this.items = data;
    if (this.items.length > 0) {
      var html = "";
      var uId = "";
      for (var i = 0; i < this.items.length; i++) {
        uId = this.items[i].name._unique();
        if (typeof this.items[i] != undefined) {
          if (self._validate(this.items[i].type) <= 0) {
            var errorClass = '<h3 class="text-danger">Invalid file format' + this.items[i].name + '</h3>'
            jQuery(".errorContent").append(errorClass);
            jQuery.remove(this.items[i]);
          }
          html += '<div class="dfiles" rel="' + uId + '"><h5>' + this.items[i].name + '</h5><div id="' + uId + '" class="progress" style="display:none;"></div></div>';
        }
      }
      jQuery("#dragAndDropFiles").append(html);
    }
  }
```

This is not all of the code, just the function that displays my error message and also shows the uploaded file on the page. I tried it with `jQuery.remove` but it does not work. Any ideas are appreciated

Comment: As an aside, `if (typeof this.items[i] != undefined) {` will always be true because `typeof` returns a string. But assuming you fix that, the test should really be _before_ you try to use `this.items[i].name`.

Answer (score 0):

what is a "file type"? I could send you a .php file that ends in .jpg, would you accept that? (I hope not!). Let the user upload the files with a warning that files X, Y, Z are not going to be accepted based on extension mismatch. Then actually test their content to see if the files are truly what their extension claims, because -and this part is important- your javascript in no way guarantees that what you're going to get is what *you* wrote your scripts to allow. Changing your script in my browser is a matter of opening my devtools and rewriting your script, then hitting ctrl-s. Now my browser will be running *my* code, not your code, and happily upload my files anyway.

Always, **always**, server-verify the user data.

Comment: We currently have serverside verify on every aspect of the data and file that is being loaded in. The client has asked us to not even load or display the file if it does not match though. I think they are going for more performance/UX design with this request. I have tired just hiding the file but ran into issue with the progress bar still running for the wrong file type.